# point of having an instance variable as final?

Tags: java

what is the point of having an instance variable as final?

isn´t it better to have that variable set as a static final variable then?

cause if it can't be changed by any of the objects, then it's the same as a class (static) variable, right?

Comment: http://renaud.waldura.com/doc/java/final-keyword.shtml

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Nope.  `static` means it's the same across all instances of the class.  `final` means it's not assignable after its initial assignment.  So two instances could have different values for a non-static final variable.

There are many reasons you might want to make a variable final; one of the best is clarity.  If I read a method and notice that the foo is final, I don't have to worry about where it's changing down below - because it isn't; it can't.  I can make more changes to code with final variables with less concern ("did I change the value of foo before or after bar, and does it matter?") because I know that some variables aren't subject to change.  It also focuses my attention on the variables that *are* subject to change - and they're the ones that deserve more attention.

Comment: but don´t you assign a value to the final instance variable when you write the class? then that means that all objects will use that value and they can´t change? or am i wrong?

Comment: Not necessarily - it can be assigned in the constructor.

Comment: You mean assign you say change. You can still change the variable declared as a final (call setters and change the state of the object for example).

Answer (score 6):

Two reasons:

1) From the class design view, it allows a programmer to rely on the fact that the field will not change since instantiation - so called "[immutable object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html)" (where applied to class members, not the object's reference). Java tutorial says:

> Immutable objects are particularly useful in concurrent applications. Since they cannot change state, they cannot be corrupted by thread interference or observed in an inconsistent state.

Immutable objects are a cornerstone of various programming styles, e.g. pure functional programming.

2) The second reasons is JVM optimizations. If all fields are final, then JVM knows the object's state can't be changed, and thus it can make many optimizations, e.g. ommiting thread safety checks etc.

Comment: @Ondra - the fact that the JVM *might* (or might not) optimize `final` fields, etc is a side-issue.  The primary motivation for using `final` should be to make your code more robust.  (And remember the advice that it is a bad idea to micro-optimize Java because the JIT compiler can do a better job if you don't!)

Comment: @Stephen:

1) I covered the "robust" aspect of final in the second paragraph. 

2) Making your small data objects immutable is definitely not a microoptimization - it can provide significant performance boosts.

"One of the most common reasons given for not making a class immutable is the belief that doing so would compromise performance. While this is true sometimes, it is often not -- and sometimes the use of immutable objects has significant, and perhaps surprising, performance advantages."

Comment: Keyword final does not make the object immutable. Please don't be confused.

Comment: @Denys, the final keyword does make the object immutable, if applied to all fields of the class of the object and these are scalar or references to immutables. But thanks, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I strongly agree with Ondra's. It's not a micro-optimization. JIT compiler doesn't need to analyze what members are unmodifiable if we explicitly set them as final.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are thinking about simple case such as:

```
 private final int num = 3;
```

That can be better written as:

```
 private static final int NUM = 3;
```

However, often you will have references to objects that are mutable, and therefore cannot be shared between classes:

```
 private final List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Children>();
```

Or perhaps, a value passed into or derived in the constructors:

```
 public final class MyThing {
      private final String name;
      public MyThing(String name) {
          this.name = name;
      }
      [...]
 }
```

Note: `final` fields can be assigned in constructors (or instance initialiser), not just as part of the declaration.

Comment: Your last example shows a `final` class.  That has nothing to do with mutability, and is only going to confuse the novice reader.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign it a value that is specific to the object instance, which you can't do with a static class variable.

Comment: so you mean when i write the class i just declare it as final. and when i have instantiated the class and call a method, the method will assign a value to it which cannot be changed?

Comment: I think you need to assign a value in the constructor, otherwise the compiler will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

It prevents other programmers from doing stupid things that they shouldn't try doing *anyway*...

Answer (score 1):

```
class A{
    public final int x;

    A(int arg){
        x = arg;  // This is legal  !!!
    }
}

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         A  a = new A(1);
         A  b = new A(2);
         System.out.printf("a.x = %d, b.x = %d", a.x, b.x);
     }
}
```